# Comparing value got from ITable (dbUnit) to a value got from domain

Tags: unit-testing, dbunit

I'm currently learning how to use dbUnit. 
I got a problem asserting values from the `ITable` and from my `domain object`. I'm guessing that the types are not the same.

Here is my code:

```
ITable expectedCategories = 
        getConnection().createDataSet().getTable( "someTable" );
assertEquals( expectedCategories.getValue( 0, "id" ), 
        domain.getId() );
```

my XML:

```
<dataset>
    <someTable id="1" />
</dataset>
```

Actually I could do this:

```
ITable expectedCategories = 
       getConnection().createDataSet().getTable( "someTable" );
assertEquals( "" + expectedCategories.getValue( 0, "id" ), 
       domain.getId().toString() );
```

to make it work, but is there another way? Or my approach of testing is improper?

Comment: What's the type of your `domain.getId()`? Your problem is with your assertion(s), not DbUnit; if that's an `int`, it can't be compared, you must use a `long` type (if that's the case and `domain.getId()` is returning an 'int')

Comment: `domain.getId()` is type of long.

Comment: Then check `expectedCategories.getValue(0, "id")`

Comment: I know its not returning `long` so how do I fix that?

Comment: You have to convert the `Object` type into a `long` value, or change the assertion to `Assert.assertTrue(expectedCategories.getValue(0, "id").equals(domain.getId()));`...same result, different "semantics".

Comment: @Machina it still fails